# Is Apple in-app-purchase transaction_id globally unique?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Are Apple in-app-purchase transaction_ids unique only for a given app or product, or are they in fact globally unique?

Example: If a transaction_id (eg `1000000019169002`) exists for an application A, is it possible for that transaction_id to again be returned for a different transaction against a second application B?

Comment: I guess only someone from Apple can answer this. It depends how an in-app transaction is made unique. If the app itself can also be identified and is part of the key then you certainly can have (appA-id, Tranid-1) and (appB-id, TranId-1) where for Apple there are two transaction where if you only take transactionid into consideration it is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the purchase info you will get both prodcut_id and transaction_id, so if you verify both together it will be guaranteed unique. It´s not possible to find any information about the transaction_id uniqeness alone.

You can also see the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Think since this answer was written apply clarified this a bit more. According to the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/originaltransactionid  it seems like the identifier is globally unique. They even state the tip: "If you maintain a database to manage your subscribers, save the original transaction identifier to uniquely identify auto-renewable subscriptions."

Answer (score 9):

The documentation for [SKPaymentTransaction.transactionIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionIdentifier) states:

> The transactionIdentifier is a string that **uniquely** identifies the processed payment.

*(emphasis mine)*

Although the documentation doesn't explicitly say *globally* unique, I believe that is the intended message, and matches more or less what I see from transaction_ids in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

[Unlike Google](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/security#:%7E:text=purchaseToken%20is%20globally%20unique%2C%20so%20you%20can%20safely%20use%20this%20value%20as%20a%20primary%20key%20in%20your%20database.), Apple is not clear about how unique the transaction_id is. [Some say](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698713) it is unique for the given product/user. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/transaction_id) apple says:

> Store the transaction_id, original_transaction_id, and product_id for each transaction, as a best practice to store transaction records for each customer.